# I can't get list of array from forEach in Firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Facing problem to get array list which is push under `forEach` operation cant be access by out of `forEach`. **I unable to get the array value(instaprofile) after forEach operation**

```
var uid = 132456;
var instaprofile = [];

var ref = firebase.database().ref("InstaAccounts");
ref.orderByChild("IgrowthId").equalTo(uid).once("value")
.then(function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (childsnap) {

        var igid = parseInt(childsnap.val().IgramuserId);

        var inprof = firebase.database().ref("InstaProfile");
        inprof.orderByChild("Userid").equalTo(igid).once("value")
        .then(function (inprofsnap) {

            var data = inprofsnap.val()[Object.keys(inprofsnap.val())[0]];

            instaprofile.push(data);

        })

    })
    console.log(instaprofile);
});
```

Comment: `inprof.orderByChild("Userid").equalTo(igid).once("value")` is asynchronous, so the pushing wont happen until after you try to log the array - asynchronous code is asynchronous

Comment: so what will be alternative for this situation ?

Comment: See answer posted below